# How to create templated nested template Parameter Packs?

Tags: c++, parameter-pack

I'm trying to build a transition-action-only state machine based on templated parameters, which can call the member-functions of another given object.

So a separate State is a single class. It should have its state-id and shall also be given all the possible events with its concrete Transition-function to the concrete state.

What I tried was the following:

```
    template<uint8_t state_id, template< class TObject, uint8_t Event, void (TObject::*Function)(void), uint8_t next_state_id> class... EventAction >
  class State {}
```

where the second template parameter pack should accept multiple possible transitions according to its concrete events. (The concrete handling of one so called "EventAction" is not the topic here)
So far the compiler doesn't complain.

But now I am stuck at that point how to call this template correctly. Do I need to create a concrete class for the parameter pack template?
What I want to look it how to use it would be something like this:

```
class S_START : public State<S_START_ID, <Object, E_E_GOSEC, actionDoOne, S_SECOND_STATE_ID>
                                       , <Object, E_E_GOTHIRD, actionDoTwo, S_THIRD_STATE_ID>>
```

Am I messing something up here or is my approach wrong from the beginning?

I can only use C++11 and some possibilities of C++14 but somehow not the full set (special compiler by TI).

Comment: A template parameter that is itself a template must be specified ... as a template, and not a specific instance of a template. That is, if your template parameter is a `template<typename T>` and you have a `template<typename T> foo`, then the corresponding parameter is `foo`, and not `foo<x>` or `foo<y>`. Beyond that, it is unclear what the rest of your program is and what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Maybe just `template<uint8_t state_id, class... EventAction>  class State {};`? I mean - from how you are trying to call it - it seems you just need a class, not class template. I might be wrong - but you need to show us what you actually want to do with EventAction pack to know for sure?

Comment: @PiotrNycz thank you! This seems to be exactly what I wanted. It is now working with:
`template< class TObject, uint8_t Event, void (TObject::*Function)(void), uint8_t next_state_id> class EventAction;

  template<uint8_t state_id, class... EventAction >`
and the derived class definition as example:
`class S_START : public ::States::State<S_START_ID, ::States::EventAction<SystemTask, E_E_CONFIGURE, &SystemTask::actionConfigure, S_START_ID>>`

Comment: It is great I could help. I put our discussion into full answer  - please accept it to show that this is a solution to your problem (for the followers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably the approach with class template is overcomplicated(overengineering) in this case.

Try just class pack:

```
template<uint8_t state_id, class... EventAction>  
class State {};
```

And use it as

```
class S_START 
    : public State<S_START_ID, 
               SomeTemplate<Object, E_E_GOSEC, actionDoOne, S_SECOND_STATE_ID>
               SomeTemplate<Object, E_E_GOTHIRD, actionDoTwo, S_THIRD_STATE_ID>>
{};
```